# Input Wildcard Constraints Snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I am new to snakemake, and I am using it to merge steps from two pipelines into a single larger pipeline. The issue that several steps create similarly named files, and I cannot find a way to limit the wildcards, so I am getting a `Missing input files for rule` error on one step that I just cannot resolve.

The full snakefile is long, and is available here: https://mdd.li/snakefile

The relevant sections are (sections of the file are missing below):

```py
wildcard_constraints:
    sdir="[^/]+",
    name="[^/]+",
    prefix="[^/]+"

# Several mapping rules here

rule find_intersecting_snps:
    input:
        bam="hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/{sdir}/{prefix}_hg19.bwt2pairs.bam"
    params:
        hornet=os.path.expanduser(config['hornet']),
        snps=config['snps']
    output:
        "hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/{sdir}/{prefix}_hg19.bwt2pairs.remap.fq1.gz",
        "hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/{sdir}/{prefix}_hg19.bwt2pairs.remap.fq2.gz",
        "hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/{sdir}/{prefix}_hg19.bwt2pairs.keep.bam",
        "hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/{sdir}/{prefix}_hg19.bwt2pairs.to.remap.bam",
        "hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/{sdir}/{prefix}_hg19.bwt2pairs.to.remap.num.gz"
    shell:
        dedent(
            """\
            python2 {params.hornet}/find_intersecting_snps.py \
            -p {input.bam} {params.snps}
            """
        )

# Several remapping steps, similar to the first mapping steps, but in a different directory

rule wasp_merge:
    input:
        "hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/{sdir}/{prefix}_hg19.bwt2pairs.keep.bam",
        "hic_mapping/wasp_results/{sdir}_{prefix}_filt_hg19.remap.kept.bam"
    output:
        "hic_mapping/wasp_results/{sdir}_{prefix}_filt_hg19.bwt2pairs.filt.bam"
    params:
        threads=config['job_cores']
    shell:
        dedent(
            """\
            {module}
            module load samtools
            samtools merge --threads {params.threads} {output} {input}
            """
        )

# All future steps use the name style wildcard, like below

rule move_results:
    input:
        "hic_mapping/wasp_results/{name}_filt_hg19.bwt2pairs.filt.bam"
    output:
        "hic_mapping/wasp_results/{name}_filt_hg19.bwt2pairs.bam"
    shell:
        dedent(
            """\
            mv {input} {output}
            """
        )
```

This pipeline is essentially doing some mapping steps in one directory structure that looks like `hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/<subdir>/<file>`, (where subdir is three different directories) then filtering the results, and doing another almost identical mapping step in `hic_remap/bowtie_results/bwt2/<subdir>/<file>`, before merging the results into an entirely new directory and collapsing the subdirectories into the file name: `hic_mapping/wasp_results/<subdir>_<file>`.

The problem I have is that the `wasp_merge` step breaks the `find_intersecting_snps` step **if** I collapse the subdirectory name into the filename. If I just maintain the subdirectory structure, everything works fine. Doing this would break future steps of the pipeline though.

The error I get is:

```
MissingInputException in line 243 of /godot/quertermous/PooledHiChip/pipeline/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule find_intersecting_snps:
hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/HCASMC5-8_HCASMC-8-CAGAGAGG-TACTCCTT_S8_L006/001_hg19.bwt2pairs.bam
```

The correct file is:
`hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/HCASMC5-8/HCASMC-8-CAGAGAGG-TACTCCTT_S8_L006_001_hg19.bwt2pairs.bam`

But it is looking for:
`hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/HCASMC5-8_HCASMC-8-CAGAGAGG-TACTCCTT_S8_L006/001_hg19.bwt2pairs.bam`

Which is not created anywhere, nor defined by any rule. I think it is somehow getting confused by the existence of the file created by the `wasp_merge` step:
`hic_mapping/wasp_results/HCASMC5-8_HCASMC-8-CAGAGAGG-TACTCCTT_S8_L006_001_filt_hg19.bwt2pairs.filt.bam`

Or possibly a downstream file (after the target that creates this error):
`hic_mapping/wasp_results/HCASMC5-8_HCASMC-8-CAGAGAGG-TACTCCTT_S8_L006_001_filt_hg19.bwt2pairs.bam`

However, I have no idea why either of those files would confuse the `find_intersecting_snps` rule, because the directory structures are totally different.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, because this error is so absurd, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both the directory name and the file name contain underscores, and in the final file name I separate the two components by underscores.

By either changing that separation character, or replacing the rule with a python function that get the names from elsewhere, I can solve the issue.

This works:

```py
rule wasp_merge:
    input:
        "hic_mapping/bowtie_results/bwt2/{sdir}/{prefix}_hg19.bwt2pairs.keep.bam",
        "hic_mapping/wasp_results/{sdir}{prefix}_filt_hg19.remap.kept.bam"
    output:
        "hic_mapping/wasp_results/{sdir}{prefix}_filt_hg19.bwt2pairs.filt.bam"
    params:
        threads=config['job_cores']
    shell:
        dedent(
            """\
            {module}
            module load samtools
            samtools merge --threads {params.threads} {output} {input}
            """
        )
```